# Loggly logback appender is really slow

Tags: logback, loggly

I'm using the Loggly logback appender as [detailed in their setup guide](https://www.loggly.com/docs/java-logback/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="LOGGLY" class="ch.qos.logback.ext.loggly.LogglyAppender">
        <endpointUrl>https://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/MY_TOKEN/tag/logback</endpointUrl>
        <pattern>%d{"ISO8601", UTC}  %p %t %c %M - %m%n</pattern>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGGLY" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Everything is working as expected (logs appearing in Loggly) but it is incredibely slow, about 1 second per log message. It's bought my application all but to a halt. Is there a performance tweak i'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the [GitHub page](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Loggly) for the `LogglyAppender` and used the `LogglyBatchAppender` instead of the one recommended by the Loggly doco. This seems to have solved the problem with long blocks writing the log message:

```
<appender name="LOGGLY" class="ch.qos.logback.ext.loggly.LogglyBatchAppender">
    <endpointUrl>https://logs-01.loggly.com/bulk/MY_TOKEN/tag/admin</endpointUrl>
    <pattern>%d{"ISO8601", UTC}  %p %t %c %M - %m%n</pattern>
    <flushIntervalInSeconds>2</flushIntervalInSeconds>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syslog appender is also pretty fast https://www.loggly.com/docs/java-logback-syslog/

Comment: Thanks for the help - but I wasn't wanting to use that as my app is deployed in a docker container and that looked like a right hassle to get working from the loggly doco.